# onload event listener called many times when loading just one page in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-sdk

I wrote a program to capture browser side implicit indicators using Javascript and PHP. The program is working very well as a standalone on a single index page. I tried adding it as an extension in Firefox so that users can access it remotely and to capture all URL visited.   As I added it, I discovered that it fires whenever a single file (such as html, jpg, css, js) has loaded thereby given me multiple loads. Please How can I make the associated files fire at the same time like a single file? Below is the code section:

```
    var linkTargetFinder = function () {
    var prefManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
    return {

        selectedTab: null,

        init: function () {
            gBrowser.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
                linkTargetFinder.run(e);
            }, false);
        },
        run: function (e) {
            var doc = e.originalTarget;

            doc.defaultView.addEventListener("unload", function (e) {
                alert('Unloading tab');
                linkTargetFinder.setCloseEvent();
            }, false);
        },
    }
}();

window.addEventListener("load", linkTargetFinder.init, false);
```

Comment: Are you adding any additional events? What is `gBrowser`?

Comment: Yes I am adding other events. gBrowser is a global variable in Firefox which is used for accessing a tabbrowser (used for holding a set of read-only views of Web documents)

Comment: Please indent your code, so we can better read it and give more context explaining what you're doing: are you using [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK)? is that code your **lib/main.js** file?